# SQL for Smarties type question: Select records from table, with some values grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database table with content like this:

| Id | Label | GroupId | DueDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | (null) | A | 1/1/2023 | 100.00 |
| 2 | (null) | A | 1/2/2023 | 101.00 |
| 3 | L1 | A | 1/3/2023 | 102.00 |
| 4 | L1 | A | 1/4/2023 | 103.00 |
| 5 | (null) | B | 1/3/2023 | 104.00 |
| 6 | L1 | C | 1/3/2023 | 105.00 |
| 7 | (null) | A | 1/4/2023 | 106.00 |
| 8 | (null) | A | 1/5/2023 | 107.00 |
| 9 | L2 | A | 1/5/2023 | 108.00 |
| 10 | L2 | A | 1/6/2023 | 109.00 |

What I'd like to accomplish with a select statement is reporting the records with the same values for 'label' and 'group id' in a single line item providing a sum() for the amount and a min() for the date.  Records that have a null value in the label column should not be grouped.

My ideal result set would look like this:

| Label | GroupId | DueDate | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (null) | A | 1/1/2023 | 100.00 |
| (null) | A | 1/2/2023 | 101.00 |
| L1 | A | 1/3/2023 | 205.00 |
| (null) | B | 1/3/2023 | 104.00 |
| L1 | C | 1/3/2023 | 105.00 |
| (null) | A | 1/4/2023 | 106.00 |
| (null) | A | 1/5/2023 | 107.00 |
| L2 | A | 1/5/2023 | 217.00 |

If it makes any difference, my RDBMS is Postgres, and the data table in question has about 500 million rows of data.

Is this possible as a single select statement using a CASE clause?  Or is it necessary to perform this as multiple selects with a UNION ALL in a manner like this:

```
select label, groupid, min(duedate), sum(amount) from my_table where label is not null
group by label, groupid
union all
select label, groupid, duedate, amount from my_table where label is null
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the two opposed where clauses in your two queries, the first query will never fetch data contained by the second query and vice versa. Therefore I think your UNION ALL idea is quite fine, no need to avoid it. Using a CASE construct is of course possible, but not required. They are usually used for conditional aggregation etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `UNION ALL` query is a good solution. If you don't want this for some reason, you can use your table's ID to get a separate "group" for each label-null row.

```
select label, groupid, min(duedate), sum(amount)
from my_table
group by case when label is null then id end, label, groupid;
```

Comment: You'd need to cast `id` as presumably it is an integer

Comment: @Stu: I don't get it. Why would grouping by an integer be bad?

Comment: Ignore comment I had assumed returning different data types in the case expression might be an issue but I tried it and seems in Postgres at least, it's not, I had needlessly tested with an *else* part.

Comment: Well, the case expression returns the ID or null (as null is the default when there is no else branch), so the resulting data type is the ID's one. There is no other data type involved, so this must work in every DBMS, not only PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yes - I had tested with an *else* part on the expression it did not need, ignore my comment I agree it's fine

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use windowed aggregates:

```
select label, groupid, duedate, amount
from (
  select Id, label, groupid, 
    First_Value(duedate) over(partition by case when label is null then Id end, groupid order by duedate) DueDate,
    Sum(amount) over(partition by case when label is null then Id end, groupid) Amount,
    Dense_Rank() over(partition by case when label is null then Id end, groupid order by duedate) rn
  from t
)t
where rn = 1
order by id;
```

Comment: This is why I love this site...even if I never use this, I just love learning about stuff I never even suspected the existence of.  Thank you for your response.